# c# composition and multiple inheritance design

Tags: c#, inheritance, composition

I'm having troubles thinking of the design for my assignment.
for the assignment I would have 2 inheritance hierarchies and I would need to mimic multiple inheritance functionalities and the cross product so robotDog, robotBigDog, robotSmallDog, attackRobotDog, etc... it seems just doing multiple inheritance would end up being 9 different class files which is probably not the best approach.

for instance:

```
public class dog{
    public virtual void bark{ Console.WriteLine("woof")};
}

public class bigDog : dog{
    public override void bark{ Console.WriteLine("WOOF")};

}

public class smallDog : dog{
    public override void bark{ Console.WriteLine("arf arf")};

}



public class robot{
    public virtual void action{ Console.WriteLine("moves")}
}

public class attackRobot : robot{
    public virtual void action{ Console.WriteLine("attacks")}
}

public class serviceRobot : robot{
    public virtual void action{ Console.WriteLine("serves")}
}
```

I was instead thinking of doing a double composition of one class containing a dog and a robot because smallDog and bigDog can stand in for dog and attackRobot and serviceRobot can stand in for robot.

```
public class robotDog{
dog myDog;
robot myRobot;
public robotDog(dog typeDog, robot typeRobot){
    myDog = typeDog;
    myRobot = typeRobot;
}
.
. various functionality 
.
```

}

is it a practical design to use double composition and also have a constructor that ask for a dog and robot? Or is there a different way to think/approach this?

Comment: This one should work for you. You can not do multiple inheritance in c#. So either you can use composition or use interfaces

Comment: From what i see in your class design, dog is separate to robot? a robot dog should still inherit from a dog. a dog is a dog whether it be robot or not.

Answer (score 3):

You can not have multiple inheritance in C#, but you can have multiple interfaces.
You can use interfaces to define what a dog and a robot look like, create some different flavours of dog and robot, then combined them into a RobotDog class that has some defaults that can be overridden, i.e.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{

    public interface IDog
    {
        void bark();
    }

    public interface IRobot
    {
        void action();
    }

    public class dog : IDog
    {
        public virtual void bark() { Console.WriteLine("woof"); }
    }
    public class bigDog : dog
    {
        public override void bark() { Console.WriteLine("WOOF"); }
    }

    public class smallDog : dog
    {
        public override void bark() { Console.WriteLine("arf arf"); }
    }

    public class robot : IRobot
    {
        public virtual void action() { Console.WriteLine("buzz, click"); }
    }

    public class attackRobot : robot
    {
        public override void action() { Console.WriteLine("attacks"); }
    }

    public class serviceRobot : robot
    {
        public override void action() { Console.WriteLine("attacks"); }
    }

    public interface IRobotDog : IDog, IRobot
    {
        IDog dog { get; set; }
        IRobot robot { get; set; }
    }

    public class RobotDog : IRobotDog
    {
        public IDog dog { get; set; }
        public IRobot robot { get; set; }

        public RobotDog()
        {
            dog = new dog();
            robot = new robot();
        }
        public RobotDog(IDog dogType)
        {
            dog = dogType;
            robot = new robot();
        }
        public RobotDog(IRobot robotType)
        {
            dog = new dog();
            robot = robotType;
        }
        public RobotDog(IDog dogType, IRobot robotType)
        {
            dog = dogType;
            robot = robotType;
        }

        public void bark() { dog.bark(); }
        public void action() { robot.action(); }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RobotDog robotDog = new RobotDog();
            robotDog.bark();
            robotDog.action();

            robotDog = new RobotDog(new bigDog(), new attackRobot());
            robotDog.bark();
            robotDog.action();

            robotDog = new RobotDog(new bigDog());
            robotDog.bark();
            robotDog.action();

            robotDog = new RobotDog(new attackRobot());
            robotDog.bark();
            robotDog.action();

            robotDog = new RobotDog();
            robotDog.dog = new bigDog();
            robotDog.bark();
            robotDog.action();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would like to expand just a bit from what Xavier has offered.  An interface is nothing more than a "contract".  In its simplest form, any class that inherits an interface MUST declare the functions / methods / properties within it.  So this way, any other object attempting to rely on its defined exposed components knows that it can, and they wont be missing.  Now, you as the developer can implement that however you want and even have an empty function, provided the function actually exists but otherwise does nothing.

```
public interface IDog
{
    void bark();
}

public interface IRobot
{
    void action();
}
```

First, just simple dog or robot.  Notice each implements their respective "REQUIRED" methods from the interface.

```
public class Dog : IDog
{
    public void bark()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Woof");

    }
}

public class Robot : IRobot
{
    public void action()
    {
        Console.Write("Activate jet pack, fly");
    }
}
```

Notice below, the robotic dog never has an  actual Dog or Robot class of its own.  However, it DOES implement both individual requirements of each interface respectively into one major class of both.

```
public class RoboticDog : IDog, IRobot
{
    public void bark()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Woof -beep- woof");

    }

    public void action()
    {
        Console.Write("Activate jet pack, flying with fur"); 
    }
}
```

Now, lets see how they operate individually.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        object testDog = new Dog();
        object testRobot = new Robot();
        object testBoth = new RoboticDog();

        WhatCanIDo(testDog);
        WhatCanIDo(testRobot);
        WhatCanIDo(testBoth);
    }

    public void WhatCanIDo( object theThing )
    {
        // Here I am checking if the object is of a class type
        // the inherits from IDog.  If so, I can type-cast it as such
        // and then call its "bark()" method as required to exist from interface.
        if (theThing is IDog)
            ((IDog)theThing).bark();

        // likewise if the object has interface of an IRobot
        if (theThing is IRobot)
            ((IRobot)theThing).action();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a small console application for you with some small tips on how to catch when you need an interface over a base class, or vice-versa.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp6
{
    class Program
    {
        interface IWalkable
        {
            void Walk(int xAxis, int yAxis);
        }

        class Robot : IWalkable
        {
            public int RobotId { get; set; }
            public Robot(int robotId)
            {
                RobotId = robotId;
                Console.Write("Robot created! \n");
            }

            public void Walk(int xAxis, int yAxis)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Im walking beep boop");
                Console.WriteLine("*walks*");
                Console.WriteLine($"Ended up in X: {xAxis} y:{yAxis}");

            }
        }

        class BadRobot : Robot
        {
            public BadRobot(int robotId) : base(robotId)
            {

            }
        }

        class Dog : IWalkable
        {
            public Dog()
            {
                Console.Write("Dog created! \n");
            }

            public void Walk(int xAxis, int yAxis)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Im walking, roof roof");
                Console.WriteLine("*walks*");
                Console.WriteLine($"Ended up in X: {xAxis} y:{yAxis}");
            }

            public virtual void Breath()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("I breath normal");
            }
        }

        class BadDog : Dog
        {
            public override void Breath()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("I breath normal");
                Console.WriteLine("But then I bark, because im bad");
            }

            //I can't "extend" an interface
            //but I can extend a virtual method from the base class
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //three tips over inheritance

            //1. If you want to abstract some *behavior*, you probably want an interface: 
            //for example here, both dogs and robots can walk. They are going to do that
            //on their own way, so each need their own proper implementation,
            //but the actions is the same thus, the interface
            // An interface is meant to group objects over shared functionality
            //so for example I can later do something like this
            

            var dog = new Dog();
            var badDog = new BadDog();
            var badRobot = new BadRobot(1);
            
            // these function doesn't care if its a dog or a robot
            void WalkOverThere(IWalkable walkable)
            {
                //some other code...
                walkable.Walk(5, 10);
            }

            //The key here is that the object pass over parameter implements the IWalk interface
            WalkOverThere(badDog);
            WalkOverThere(badRobot);

            //Please notice that for each class that inherits "IWalkable"
            //There will be a new implementation, so in this case, if 
            //all the robots inherit from the class robot, all will walk the same way
            //In that, I cannot extend, or modify how that method is performed in the base
            //class from the child class


            //2. Now, the case is different when we talk about some functionality that could change 
            //for any child implementation of the base class. Think about the breath functionality
            //A robot can't breathe, but a dog does. And given that every dog breaths differently
            //it makes sense to create and virtual method, that means that I can reconfigure how
            //the breath method behaves. For example:

            dog.Breath();
            badDog.Breath();

            //3. Another thing that is useful to take into account is that
            //whenever I can't create a given object without some piece of information, 
            //it makes sense to create the necessity of that data in the constructor.
            //take for example in this code that I cannot create a robot without a valid int robotId 
            //This practice enforces me to create a robot like:
            //var robot = new Robot(100); where 100 is the id
            //var robot = new Robot(); the compile would not allow that
        }
    }
}
```